# Dynamic array of array of int in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, multi-dimensional-scaling

How can an array of array of int be declared outside the main, then build inside the main once we know the length of the array of array we want to build, if one dimension is already known.

For example, if the array should be `array[numberofargs][2]`, where the dimension `2` is already known but not `numberofargs` before execution of main.

Comment: Outside a function you can not do this.

Comment: Its not possible to statically allocate an array like you mentioned. You will have to dynamically allocate the array inside main. There are multiple ways to do that. Refer this link for more information : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

Comment: What I meant is I want to dynamically allocate the array inside the main, but declare it outside the main.

Comment: It was to create global array of pipes which have two ends, (read and write).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is just to declare for example a pointer in a file scope like

```
int ( *array )[2] = NULL;
```

and then in one of functions allocate a memory for the array.
For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*array)[2] = NULL;

int main(void) 
{
    int numberofargs = 5;
    array = malloc( sizeof( int[numberofargs][2] ) );

    //...
    
    free( array );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Or the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array = NULL;

int main(void) 
{
    int numberofargs = 5;

    array = malloc( numberofargs * sizeof( *array ) );
    

    for ( int i = 0; i < numberofargs; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = malloc( sizeof( *array[i] ) );
    }

    //...
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberofargs; i++ )
    {
        free( array[i] );
    }
    free( array );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to create an array where only the second dimension is known. What you can do is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SECOND_DIM 2

int *array;

// returns array[x][y]
int foo(int *array, int x, int y) {
  return *(array+x*SECOND_DIM+y);
}

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
  if(!argv[0]) return 0;
  
  array = malloc(args*SECOND_DIM*sizeof(int));
  for(int i=0;i<args; i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<SECOND_DIM; j++)
      *(array+(i*SECOND_DIM)+j) = (i+1)*100+j;
  }

  printf("array[0][0]: %d\n", foo(array,0,0)); // array[0][0]
  printf("array[0][1]: %d\n", foo(array,0,1)); // array[0][1]

  free(array);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int (*array)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int[numberofargs][2]));
```

And then when you're finished with it:

```
free(array);
```

Comment: He wants to do this outside any function.